# SuperTab Plugin doesn't work together with the omnicomplete feature (<C-X><C-O>)

Tags: vim

I am using VIM to code PHP. I also have indexed my project folder with ctags. It works pretty well with omnicompletion, so when I type for example `$someObject-><C-X><C-O>` it shows all methods of the object.

I am working with the SuperTab plugin too though, and when this plugin is active, I cannot hit  anymore. Nothing happens, only below in the status bar INSERT becomes (insert).

Does anyone have an idea why  doesn't work with SuperTab?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, an update to the newest version of SuperTab (0.51) helped solve the problem